# compiling googletest program on linux openSUSE with g++,make,cmakelists

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, makefile, cmake

So I tried to use the googletest library ( https://github.com/google/googletest ). First I compiled it with cmake:

```
marton@linux-clwa:~/documents/github/googletest/googletest/cmake> cmake ..
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/local/bin/python (found version "3.4.5")  
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE   
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/marton/documents/github/googletest/googletest/cmak
e
marton@linux-clwa:~/documents/github/googletest/googletest/cmake> make
Scanning dependencies of target gtest
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.o
[ 50%] Linking CXX static library libgtest.a
[ 50%] Built target gtest
Scanning dependencies of target gtest_main
[ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/gtest_main.dir/src/gtest_main.cc.o
[100%] Linking CXX static library libgtest_main.a
[100%] Built target gtest_main
```

and tried to compile it with g++, make:

```
Thu Mar 16; 22:45:19; marton;~/documents/github/fmi_summer_2017/chisleni_metodi ;  $  g++ -isystem /home/marton/documents/github/googletest/googletest/include -L/home/marton/documents/github/googletest/googletest  -pthread -lgthread 002.razd_razl.cpp -o test
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lgthread
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am not sure if this error is due to my compiler/distro but I have installed these packages:

gcc-32bit gcc48-32bit glibc-devel-32bit libasan0-32bit libatomic1-32bit libgomp1-32bit
libitm1-32bit

So I thought that the lgtest is the problem and as poor-brained coder I decided to remove it and the result is a big list of undefined functions, namespaces and variables.

So I tried this repo: ( https://github.com/snikulov/google-test-examples ).
Everything was working correctly meaning that the problem is not with my compiler.but the repo was using cmakelists.

What am I doing wrong, what do I have to do to compile my program?

I know the fascist geeks will downvote but I searched google,youtube, the gtest repo and there is no explanation anywhere of how to compile your program your test via g++. So where can I find information about that ?

Which is it better to use make or CMakeLists ?

Comment: Where do you find that command line for build tests? Why do you need `gthread` (GLib Threads) library for your tests?

Comment: if by gthread you mean the -lgthread, I am not sure if it's required or not but if I try to compile my program without it, my terminal gets filled with errors

Answer (score 0):

For compiling, if you want to use a CMakeLists.txt, added to a parent one via `add_subdirectory`, you can do something like this. (Taken from the Google Test Documentation)

In `ProjectRoot/CMakeLists.txt`

```
...
set(GTEST_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest)
add_subdirectory(build_test)
...
```

In `ProjectRoot/build_test/CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

# Download and unpack googletest at configure time
configure_file(CMakeLists.txt.in ${GTEST_OUTPUT_PATH}/download/CMakeLists.txt)

execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -G "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" .
  RESULT_VARIABLE result
WORKING_DIRECTORY ${GTEST_OUTPUT_PATH}/download )
if(result)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "CMake step for googletest failed: ${result}")
endif()
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build .
  RESULT_VARIABLE result
WORKING_DIRECTORY ${GTEST_OUTPUT_PATH}/download )
if(result)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Build step for googletest failed: ${result}")
endif()

# Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker
# settings on Windows
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

# Add googletest directly to our build. This defines
# the gtest and gtest_main targets.
add_subdirectory(${GTEST_OUTPUT_PATH}/src
                 ${GTEST_OUTPUT_PATH}/build)
```

In `ProjectRoot/build_test/CMakeLists.txt.in`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.2)

project(googletest-download NONE)

include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(googletest
  GIT_REPOSITORY    https://github.com/google/googletest.git
  GIT_TAG           master
  SOURCE_DIR        "${GTEST_OUTPUT_PATH}/src"
  BINARY_DIR        "${GTEST_OUTPUT_PATH}/build"
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
  BUILD_COMMAND     ""
  INSTALL_COMMAND   ""
  TEST_COMMAND      ""
)
```

What this allows us to do is clone a fresh copy of GoogleTest from their repo, and then builds it with the correct command arguments. (You can then after this is completed link to it as you normally would. ) I would recommend trying to set it up this to ensure that there aren't any issues in how you are building it. The only requirements for GTest is a c++98 compatible compiler, and make. You can see the complete (very minimal) requirements here: [Linux Requirements](https://github.com/google/googletest#linux-requirements)

Comment: I will try it now, the problem is that I am not at all familiar with this technology and if I have, I wouldn't be able to modify it... so is there a chance that in future I will have to modify it ? Also how do I compile with this cmakelist ?

Comment: You can certainly modify it to fit your needs. To build it you would in your project root directory run `cmake .`, and then upon completion you will run `make`.